# Mach-O Error using drawGlossAndGradient()

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, mach-o

Got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_drawGlossAndGradient", referenced from:
  -[CustomHeader drawRect:] in CustomHeader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

With this code:

```
drawGlossAndGradient(context, _coloredBoxRect, lightColor, darkColor);
```

A similar error happens with this bit of code:

```
CGMutablePathRef arcPath = createArcPathFromBottomOfRect(arcRect, 4.0);
```

I imported some .h and .m files out of another project which works fine. I added all frameworks to the new project but it still pops out this warning. I never dealt with this kind of error and would be  grateful if someone could help me.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add CoreGraphics.framework to your project.

Actually, you don't need add any `#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>` in your file. You should add the framework like it's:
[image]

Comment: I did `#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>` in my CustomHeader.m and my MasterViewController.m but I'm still not able to build the app.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It works now, the problem was that I forgot to `#import` an other `.h` File.

Comment: Could you please specify which .h-file you forgot.. It might help others (like myself) ;)